# How to load/execute a view template from a string in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've developed a CakePHP plugin that allows the site administrator to define custom reports as a list of SQL queries that are executed and the results displayed by a .ctp template.

Now I need to allow the administrator to edit the template, stored in the DB together with the report.
Therefore I need to render a template that is inside a string and not in a .ctp file and I could not find anything in the core that helps.

I considered initially the approach to write the templates in .ctp files and load them from there, but I suspect this solution is rigged with flaws re: the location of the files and related permissions.

A better solution seems to override the View class and add a method to do this.

Can anyone suggest a better approach ?

P.S. Security is not a concern here, since the administrator is basically a developer without access to the code.

Comment: IMHO implementing things transparently on view class level is the way to go, ideally using templating functionality that is safe against PHP injections, as security should _always_ be a concern if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this in an AppView class, copying how core evaluates templates (using eval instead of include). I am not sure how to secure this more though, besides to have some kind of checksum of the code to prevent DB manipulations.

Comment: Although my renderString() method in AppView worked, I ended up using Twig instead to avoid any security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP *2*.0: 
The [`View::render()`](https://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-View.html#587) method imports the template file using

### [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> The `include` statement includes and **evaluates** the specified file.

The evaluated template is immediately executed in whatever scope it was included. To duplicate this functionality, you would need to use

### [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

> **Caution:** The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

*(This warning is speaking to you, specifically)*

---

*...if you wish to continue...* Here is a basic example of how you might achieve this:

```
$name = 'world';
$template = 'Hello <?php echo $name ?>... <br />';

echo $template;
// Output: Hello ...

eval(' ?>' . $template . '<?php ');
// Output: Hello world...
```

*Which is (almost) exactly the same as:*

```
$name = 'world';
$template = 'Hello <?php echo $name ?>... <br />';
file_put_contents('path/to/template.php', $template);

include 'path/to/template.php';
```

*Except people won't yell at you for using `eval()`*

---

In your CakePHP application:

`app/View/EvaluatorView.php`

```
class EvaluatorView extends View
{
    public function renderRaw($template, $data = [])
    {
        if (empty($data)) {
            $data = $this->viewVars;
        }
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);

        ob_start();
        eval(' ?>' . $template . '<?php ');
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        return $output;
    }
}
```

`app/Controller/ReportsController.php`

```
class ReportsController extends AppController
{
    public function report()
    {
        $this->set('name', 'John Galt');
        $this->set('template', 'Who is <?php echo $name; ?>?');
        $this->viewClass = 'Evaluator';
    }
}
```

`app/View/Reports/report.ctp`

```
// Content ...

$this->renderRaw($template);
```

---

Alternatively, you may want to check out existing templating engines like: [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), [Twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/), and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will integrate this with a checksum of the stored code just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. Maybe create a variable that will store the generated code and just 'echo' this variable in ctp file.

I had similar problem (cakephp 3)
Controller method:

```
public function preview($id = null) {

    $this->loadModel('Templates');
    $tempate = $this
        ->Templates
        ->findById($id)
        ->first();

    if(is_null($template)) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Template not found'));
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    $html = $template->html_content;
    $this->set(compact('html'));
}
```

And preview.ctp is just:

```
<?= $html
```

Comment: Thanks. True, but that will work if the template contains HTML code only. I need variables because the template is a way to customize the report output.

Comment: I think You can extend this solution using some kind of tokens in templates. For example: `<div>{{variable_name}}</div>` Before displaying You can catch all tokens using regexp `preg_match_all("/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/", $input, $variables);` and replace them with dynamic content.